# Ubuntu 13.04 - mount.cifs always ask for password

Tags: mount, cifs

I've created a script to mount the windows server network shares, but it keeps me asking for the network password. I've already tried setting the `PASSWD` env var and setting the password in the command.

Here's what I have:

```
sudo mount.cifs //IP/Utils /media/Data/Utils -o username=sergio, password=MyPassword..., uid=sergio, file_mod=0755, dir_mode=0755, gid=sergio, workgroup=myworkgroup
```

I tried also with `sec=ntlm` (looked at another question, don't remember where) but no avail.

Why it keeps me asking the password?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `mount.cifs` [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/mount.cifs.8.html):

> Options to mount.cifs are specified as a comma-separated list of key=value pairs.

So there should be no space between the options, only commas:

```
sudo mount.cifs //IP/Utils /media/Data/Utils -o username=sergio,password=MyPassword...,uid=sergio,file_mode=0755,dir_mode=0755,gid=sergio,workgroup=myworkgroup
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, AskUbuntu didn't notified me [?]. I already tried that, it show's me `mount error(22): Invalid argument`

Comment: Ok, trimming white spaces and changing file_mod to file_mode do the trick. Thanks!